# Hybrid HDD randomly parks

Tags: hybrid-storage

My new laptop has a hybrid hard drive as a secondary drive (used for data, program files, etc.) and uses an SDD as a primary drive (mostly just the OS, but some frequently-used programs - e.g. web browsers, Office, etc. - are kept there also). This is my first experience with a SSD in my personal computer, and my first experience with any hybrid drive, so I'm still trying to get used to their behavior.

One thing I've noticed, which has been somewhat worrisome, is that the HDD seems to spin down and up, while I'm using the system, for no readily apparent reason. I can tell because the sound of the read/write heads being parked is still relatively audible and distinctive, despite most other operations being fairly silent. (I actually kind-of miss the days when you could easily tell whether a HDD was working just by listening - who needs a status light when you can hear the read/write heads thrashing away from across the room?) If I'm listening very carefully, I can also hear when it spins back up. Sometimes it comes back up rather quickly, sometimes it's down for several minutes or more.

After giving it some thought, I believe I know what's going on but I wanted to ask here for confirmation (and posterity for anyone else in my situation).

The drive in question is a Seagate model `ST1000LM014`. It has a 64 MB buffer, a 1 TB 5400 RPM HDD, and 8 GB NAND Flash cache.

For a drive that only handles infrequently-used programs and user documents, I'm guessing 8 GB is plenty of room to cache files currently in-use. So, my theory goes that the drive initially spins up to pull necessary data into the NAND Flash memory and then parks itself when it's done. After that it only spins up when data is needed that's not in the cache, or when write operations need to be performed, and parks again when it's no longer needed.

Is my theory more or less correct? Are there other reasons I should expect the drive to spin up/down during normal system use, absent any defects or malfunctions? Is all this starting and stopping detrimental to the health of the drive, or does the idle time balance it out?

I don't expect it makes a substantial difference, but the OS on the system is Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Your theory is mostly correct in accordance with [this](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9209863/Users_frustrated_with_Seagate_s_next_gen_hybrid_drive) article. *"Much of the problem involves a Momentus XT feature called Advanced Power Management (APM), which automatically spins down the hard disk to manage power use and increase mechanical life span."*. I have the 750g Momentus XT and I have zero complaints in its performance. I've used it as a boot drive, storage drive, and now I have it installed in my laptop for a dual hard drive, dual boot system and it works brilliantly.

Comment: @slow_excellence Thanks for the link. I'm using NirSoft's DiskSmartView to check the S.M.A.R.T. statistics on my drive, but I'm having a hard time figuring out which value should indicate the "spin up/down cycles" mentioned in the article.

Comment: @lszi I haven't used DiskSmartView but from what I can gather, this is represented by the "Start/Stop Count" value.

Comment: @slow_excellence That's currently at 175, which seems *really* low for the time I've had the drive and how often I hear it park.

Comment: @lszi Maybe DiskSmartView is only showing the amount of counts that it's recorded since you installed the software? That is pretty low though, I was expecting something in the thousands at the very least. In the article the guy had 65k counts but I'd consider that as more of an extreme case. Keep an eye on it in the meantime, you needn't worry unless you start getting errors and/or your drive starts making grinding noises. I was never really able to hear my XT over my computer's old fans (practically jet engines) so I really can't relate with the near constant spin up/down you've described.

Comment: @slow_excellence My laptop's fans can get pretty loud too, especially playing Kerbal Space Program. Still, I can sometimes hear the drive park even then. I guess I just got sensitive to HDD sounds, since they used to be the primary means of knowing if your computer was actually working when it might otherwise appear unresponsive.